# EXE file Error: Failed to extract C:\Users\Sagar\PycharmProjects\FiverrFirstProject\main.xlsx: failed to open target file! fopen: Invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have made a Birthday reminder system using python, I have a xlsx(excel) file in the folder which contains name and date of birth. When I Run the python code it reads the xlsx(excel) file and compare with today's date with Birthdate which is mentioned in the excel file. And if the date is equals to todays date it send reminder on my email id. And it runs Perfectly.

So after that when, I convert the python and xlsx file in exe. And runs the exe file it shows me the error:

```
Failed to extract C:\Users\Sagar\PycharmProjects\FiverrFirstProject\main.xlsx: failed to open target file!
fopen: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the xlsx file as a data file in your project like

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data main.xlsx
```